Duda como filtrar datos o valores repetidos de manera independiente Python, Pandas, Excel y datos Repetidos
necesito ayuda con una funcion, el combobox despliega una lista de datos (SIDREP) al seleccionar uno de los sidrep cargara los datos asociados al sidrep y completara los campos en una interfaz.(Ver Imagen) El combobox se alimenta desde un Excel, columna especifica (N SIDREP) y cada campo de la interfaz también se alimenta desde ese excel, el problema radica es que la función considera los valores repetidos  como si fueran filas múltiples y solo considera la primera o la ultima fila al tener un sidrep repetido, trata ese sidrep como si se tratara del que ya se selecciono o como si ambos sidrep fueran un solo sidrep, pero cada sidrep  independiente de que este repetido se debe tratar como un proceso distinto, intente agregar la columna "Numero de Proceso" como un criterio de filtro pero aun asi sigo sin poder lograr que cargue los datos asociados a  cada sidrep de manera independiente, para  los sidrep distintos funciona bien,
fila 2/sidrep 111/ N° Proceso 1,
fila 3/sidrep 111/ N° Proceso 2,
fila 4/sidrep 222/ N° Proceso 3,
y asi Sucesivamente...
no puedo agregarle identificadores al sidrep (es un valor absoluto y unico)
espero haberme explicado bien, si alguien sabe como puedo filtrar de manera independiente cada fila para que los campos se completen con la selección correspondiente estare eternamente agradecido,muchas gracias
  def actualizar_combobox_sidrep(self, event=None):
    new_sidrep = self.combobox_numero_sidrep.get()

    if new_sidrep != self.current_sidrep:
        self.current_sidrep = new_sidrep
        # Para verificar el SIDREP seleccionado
        print("SIDREP seleccionado:", self.current_sidrep)

        if new_sidrep:
            archivo_excel_path = resource_path(
                os.path.join("data", "Registro_Verificacion.xlsx"))
            try:
                datos = pd.read_excel(archivo_excel_path)

                # Filtra los datos para obtener todas las filas correspondientes al SIDREP seleccionado
                filas_seleccionadas = datos[(
                    datos["SIDREP Nº"] == int(new_sidrep))]

                if not filas_seleccionadas.empty:
                    # Imprime todas las filas correspondientes al SIDREP seleccionado
                    print("Filas correspondientes al SIDREP seleccionado:")
                    print(filas_seleccionadas)

                    fila_seleccionada = filas_seleccionadas.iloc[-1]

                    # Actualiza los campos de la interfaz con los datos de la fila seleccionada
                    self.lugar_descarga.set(
                        fila_seleccionada["Lugar Descarga"])
                    self.nombre_cliente.set(fila_seleccionada["Generador"])
                    self.nombre_transportista.set(
                        fila_seleccionada["Transportista"])
                    self.tipo_contenedor.set(
                        fila_seleccionada["Contenedor"])
                    self.tipo_residuo.set(fila_seleccionada["Residuo"])
                    self.fecha_verificacion.set(
                        fila_seleccionada["Fecha Verificacion"])
                    self.cantidad_residuos.set(
                        fila_seleccionada["Cantidad Residuos"])
                    self.peso_residuo.set(
                        fila_seleccionada["Peso Residuo (kg)"])

                else:
                    print("No se encontraron datos para el SIDREP seleccionado")
            except FileNotFoundError:
                return
        else:
            self.limpiar_campos()




Si tus valores en el ComboBox están repetidos, usar simplemente get() no te permite diferenciar cual de ellos está seleccionado. Para diferenciarlos usa el método ComboBox.current() que te retorna el indice del valor seleccionado.
Una vez que tengas el indice es solo cuestión de mapearlo a la fila del DataFrame correspondiente. Si todos los valores de la columna SIDREP termina en el ComboBox es simplemente cuestión de usar el indice retornado por current para obtener la fila directamente:
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


csv = StringIO("""
Número de Proceso,Fecha Verificacion,SIDRED Nº,Generador,Residuo
1,07-04-2024,111,AB Arriendo SA,ABOSORVENTE TIERRA
2,07-04-2024,111,AB Arriendo SA,RESIDUO SOLIDOS
3,08-04-2024,222,Agricola Millahue, POLVOS DE LOS SISTEMAS...
""")


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args,**kwargs):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self._datos = None
        
        tk.Label(self, text="SIDREP Nº:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="w", padx=10)
        self.combobox_numero_sidrep = ttk.Combobox(self)
        self.combobox_numero_sidrep.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="w", padx=10)

        self.nombre_cliente = tk.StringVar(self)
        tk.Label(self, text="Transportista").grid(row=0, column=2, sticky="w", padx=10)
        tk.Entry(
            self, textvariable=self.nombre_cliente
        ).grid(row=0, column=3, sticky="w", padx=10)

        self.fecha_verificacion = tk.StringVar(self)
        tk.Label(self, text="Fecha Verificación").grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="w", padx=10)
        tk.Entry(
            self, textvariable=self.fecha_verificacion
        ).grid(row=1, column=3, sticky="w", padx=10)

        self.tipo_residuo = tk.StringVar(self)
        tk.Label(self, text="Residuo").grid(row=2, column=2, sticky="w", padx=10) 
        tk.Entry(
            self, textvariable=self.tipo_residuo
        ).grid(row=2, column=3, sticky="w", padx=10)
        
        self.combobox_numero_sidrep.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', self.actualizar_combobox_sidrep)
        self.cargar_datos()

    def cargar_datos(self):
        self._datos = pd.read_csv(csv)
        combo_values = self._datos["SIDRED Nº"].to_list()
        self.combobox_numero_sidrep.config(values=combo_values)
        self.combobox_numero_sidrep.current(0)
        self.actualizar_combobox_sidrep()

    def actualizar_combobox_sidrep(self, event=None):
        indice = self.combobox_numero_sidrep.current()
        sidrep = self.combobox_numero_sidrep.get()
        # filas_seleccionadas = self._datos[self._datos["SIDRED Nº"] == int(sidrep)]
        # fila_seleccionada = filas_seleccionadas.loc[indice]
        
        # o directamente
        fila_seleccionada = self._datos.iloc[indice]

        self.nombre_cliente.set(fila_seleccionada["Generador"])
        self.fecha_verificacion.set(fila_seleccionada["Fecha Verificacion"])
        self.tipo_residuo.set(fila_seleccionada["Residuo"])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("550x200")
    App(root).pack(expand=True, fill=tk.BOTH)
    root.mainloop()


Si no asignas todos los valores al ComboBox o no lo haces el mismo orden, la idea sigue siendo válida, simplemente asocia cada indice a una clave única que puedas usar luego para identificar la fila.
